# Java: Dealing with multiple complex interfaces without duplicate code

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I am working with a Java API which requires me to implement a number of fairly large interfaces. However generally there is only one or two details that actually vary between implementations, so I made some abstract base classes to provide most of the implementation.

However now Ive come across cases where I need to extend from some other class and/or implement multiple such interfaces, and so I am unable to extend my abstract base classes.

In C++ I was able to use multiple inheritance, and also use some other tricks like below. However Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance, or generics to be used in this way.

```
class MyClass : public HelperForInterfaceA, public HelperForInterfaceB {...};
class template<class BASE> MyHelper : public BASE {...};
```

The best idea I have right now is to have the concrete implementation of my abstract helper class as a field, and then make all the interface methods forward to that field instance, with the field having a reference to the main object to implement the last details if needed.

```
class MyClass extends A implements IB, IC {
    private static class B extends BAbstractHelper {
        private A a;
        public B(A a, int size) {
            super(size);
            this.a = a;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean foo(int x, int y) {
            return a.foo(x, y);
        }
    }
    private static class C extends CAbstractHelper {
        ...
    }


    private B b;
    private C c;
    private int range;

    @Override
    public boolean foo(int x, int y) {
        return x*x + y*y <= range*range;
    }

    @Override
    public float bar(float x, int y, String s) {
        return b.bar(x,y,s);
    }

    ...
}
```

However this seems a bit of a pain, with a lot of wrapper methods required. Is there a better way of dealing with this?

Comment: very good question. I am afraid it will be pain :-(

Answer (score 1):

A Java best practice is to prefer composition over inheritance. Keeps things simpler but creates more boilerplate code. You have the right idea to create delegate methods. A good Java IDE can generate all the boilerplate delegate methods code for you. Other languages on the JVM like Scala (with traits) make this easier.

Comment: On the other hand i think people take composition too far as a reaction to the "favor composition over inheritance" trend.  And it's possible the reason this guy is faced with this code full of difficult interfaces.  If you give very careful consideration to your class structure then inheritance is often a great solution.   It's rare that I need to use composition at all as nearly everything can be represented nicely using inheritance.  Sounds like heresy but there's a reason the founders were so excited about inheritance.  It's an extremely useful tool for structuring.

Comment: Now that Java supports default method implementations in interfaces, this is much easier to do via multiple interfaces without needing to create delegate methods.